# Invalid Syntax: function doesn't return value

Tags: python, list, function, return, syntax-error

I get an Invalid Syntax error for my code, but I have no idea why.
My code should create a 2 dimensional list of zeroes and then change one of the zeros to a one, and check certain list values, to see if it will return the 1, or just zeros.
I define a function that should return a list of the adjacent cell values, but for some reason the syntax error arises. Here is my code:

```
def test(x,y):
    spotX = [(x-1)%height,0,(x+1)%height]
    spotY = [(y-1)%height,0,(y+1)%height]
    val = []
    for a in range(3):
        for b in range(3):
            if a and b != 2:
                val.append(newBoard[spotX[a]][spotY[b]]
    return val
```

The syntax error is that "return val" line.

Comment: There's a missing `)` at the end of `val.append(newBoard[spotX[a]][spotY[b]]`

Comment: FYI, syntax errors often get marked as being in a line or two after the actual error if the mistake is a missing delimiter (like `)`), becuase the interpreter will continue looking for that `)` and find a `return` statement, or something that doesn't belong inside `()`.  That's where it's upset, but not where you need to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the error is mentioning the `return val` line is because it believes that it is part of the append function, when actually you just forgot to close the bracket.

```
val.append(newBoard[spotX[a]][spotY[b]])
```